# Tor browser taking longer to launch after update on ubuntu 18.04 system

Tags: configuration, update, startup

I have been using tor browser for some time now, 4 to 5 months maybe. Earlier it took 1-2 minutes for tor browser to launch. But then an upgrade happened, and now it takes 15-20 minutes. I'd click the app icon from the list and nothing would happen, then all of a sudden 15 or so minutes, I see the screen saying "tor browser is starting."

Context: Using ubuntu 18.04 system. There has been no update to ubuntu version since I started using tor. I installed tor using the apt-get command.

I am a layman, and can only tell what I see, no other diagnosis skills.

Thank you for whatever help you might provide.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Tor, then rebooting your system, then reinstalling it? This usually does the trick for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tor Browser launching very slowly](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/20029/tor-browser-launching-very-slowly)